# Django IntegrityError at / NOT NULL constraint failed: myapp_paitents.father_id

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am creating a fairly simple app in Django where 3 models are there Paitents,Father and Mother i am assigning foreignkey of father mother in paitents model, Intention is to get paitent detail including parent's details and save it to database but i am getting IntegrityError at / NOT NULL constraint failed: myapp_paitents.father_id I tried to search in same issue but i did't got one. Please someone help me with that.

models.py file

```
from django.db import models

class Father(models.Model):
    f_name          = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    f_age           = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    f_occupation    = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    f_edu           = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    f_income        = models.FloatField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.f_name

class Mother(models.Model):
    m_name          = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    m_age           = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    m_occupation    = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    m_edu           = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    m_income        = models.FloatField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.m_name

class Paitents(models.Model):
    p_name          = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    p_age           = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    p_edu           = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    p_add_com       = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
    p_add           = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
    father        = models.ForeignKey(Father, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mother        = models.ForeignKey(Mother, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.p_name
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        paitent = Paitents()
        fathers = Father()
        mothers = Mother()

        fathers.f_name = request.POST.get('f_name')
        fathers.f_age = request.POST.get('f_age')
        fathers.f_occupation = request.POST.get('f_occupation')
        fathers.f_edu = request.POST.get('f_edu')
        fathers.f_income = request.POST.get('f_income')

        mothers.m_name = request.POST.get('m_name')
        mothers.m_age = request.POST.get('m_age')
        mothers.m_occupation = request.POST.get('m_occupation')
        mothers.m_edu = request.POST.get('m_edu')
        mothers.m_income = request.POST.get('m_income')

        paitent.p_name = request.POST.get('p_name')
        paitent.p_age = request.POST.get('p_age')
        paitent.p_edu = request.POST.get('p_edu')
        paitent.p_add = request.POST.get('p_add')
        paitent.p_add_com = request.POST.get('p_add_com')

        fathers.save()
        mothers.save()
        paitent.save()


        return render(request,'paitent_d/home.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'paitent_d/home.html')
```

Html page

```
<form action="" method="POST">
            {%csrf_token%}
            <h1>Paitent Details</h1>
            <hr>
            <!--<input type="text" id="p_ID" name="p_ID" placeholder="ID"><br>-->
            <input type="text" id="p_name" name="p_name" placeholder="Name"><br>
            <input type="text" id="p_age" name="p_age" placeholder="Age"><br>
            <input type="text" id="p_edu" name="p_edu" placeholder="Education"><br>
            <input type="text" id="p_add_com" name="p_add_com" placeholder="Communication Address"><br>
            <input type="text" id="p_add" name="p_add" placeholder="Address"><br>
            <hr>
            <input type="text" id="f_name" name="f_name" placeholder="Father's Name"><br>
            <input type="text" id="f_age" name="f_age" placeholder="Age"><br>
            <input type="text" id="f_occupation" name="f_occupation" placeholder="Occupation"><br>
            <input type="text" id="f_edu" name="f_edu" placeholder="Education"><br>
            <input type="text" id="f_income" name="f_income" placeholder="Income"><br>
            <hr>
            <input type="text" id="m_name" name="m_name" placeholder="Mother's Name"><br>
            <input type="text" id="m_age" name="m_age" placeholder="Age"><br>
            <input type="text" id="m_occupation" name="m_occupation" placeholder="Occupation"><br>
            <input type="text" id="m_edu" name="m_edu" placeholder="Education"><br>
            <input type="text" id="m_income" name="m_income" placeholder="Income"><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
        </form>
```

Error which i got

```
  File "/home/rahul/dev/health/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: myapp_paitents.father_id
```

[image]

Comment: Unrealted but 1/ your models design is plain wrong (you should have one single "Person"  model with self-referential (nullable) FKs for father and mother and a "is_patient" flag, and you should store the birthdate, not the age) and 2/ by all means use ModelForms.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I'll make sure to improve it. 

Comment: you're welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving `Paitents` record without assigning `father` and `mother` ID's and thus you got this error - your schema doesn't allow (by default) to have foreign keys set to null:

```
father        = models.ForeignKey(Father, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
mother        = models.ForeignKey(Mother, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You need to or provide proper values:

```
paitent.father = father
paitent.mother = mother
paitent.save()
```

or change schema to allow this fields to be null:

```
father        = models.ForeignKey(Father, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
mother        = models.ForeignKey(Mother, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```